# SQL Server on QNAP. Error: 17836, Severity: 20, State: 17

Tags: sql-server, qnap

I have installed SQL Server 2022 on my Qnap, but I get this error:

> Error: 17836, gravedad: 20, estado: 17.
> 2023-02-28 20:31:29.17 Logon
> Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library. [CLIENTE: 10.0.3.1]

Does someone know how to resolve it?

Comment: *"I have installed SQL Server 2020"* Unlikely, there wasn't a release in 2020; there was a release in 2019 and then the next was in 2022.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I corrected the version. Anyway, I installed the 2019 and I had the same problem.

Comment: When are you getting this error message? Are you trying to connect with telnet or some other non-TDS-protocol client?

Comment: I get the message when I open the SQL Server console. I tried to connect with telnet and the qnap refused the connection, but I do not know how to open a particular port on qnap

Comment: TDS (Tabular Data Streams) is a binary protocol, you can't connect to it with telnet and expect to get some kind of CLI like you'd get with IMAP, POP3 and SMTP. You need to connect to it using an SQL Server client library, such as `mssql` or `tedious` in NodeJS, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` or `System.Data.SqlClient` in .NET, etc., or a tool like SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), `isql`, `osql` or `sqlcmd`.